# Rolling in 3D using Torque, Angular Momentum/Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, torque, angular-velocity, moment-of-inertia

I'm stuggling to get a simulation working correctly. Below you can see what I am attempting to do. You can also [view it here](http://mathb.in/13413?key=5e016539cf68c805e8fa92cecfa35118e1a036c2).

Can you spot where I'm going wrong?

### (Calculated at start)

### 1) Inertia Sphere

$$ I = \frac{2}{5} MR^2 $$  (I = 1.161)
$$ I_{body} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.161 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1.161 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1.161 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ I_{body}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.861 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.861 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.861 \end{bmatrix}$$

### 2) Inverse Inertia Tensor

$$ I^{-1} = RI_{body}^{-1}R^T $$

---

### (Calculated each update)

### 3) Torque

CP = Vector from center of mass to contact point.
SumF = impulse force + friction. (impulse was converted by: impulse / dt)
$$ T = CP \times \sum_{F} $$

### 4) Angular Momentum

$$ L = L + T *dt $$

### 5) Angular Velocity

$$ w(0) = I^{-1}L $$

### 6) Skew Matrix

$$ w(^*) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -w_z(t) & w_y(t) \\ w_z(t) & 0 & -w_x(t) \\ -w_y(t) & w_x(t) & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

### 7) Rotation Matrix

$$ R = R + dt \times w(^*) \times R $$

Comment: What is the question, i.e. which results do you believe are wrong?

Comment: The balls rotate but keep getting faster until they stop (probably hitting max/inf). I think the Torque/Angular Momentum calculation may be wrong but I'm not sure which is why I posted all the steps.

Comment: You seem to be following the correct steps. See http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf for more details on how to do this. Your issue might be with the integrator $L=L+T\,{\rm d}t$ which typically adds energy to the system.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but it looks like you're using a simple Euler method to integrate and make your system proceed. This can be unstable in oscillating systems, and you can fix it by using the Euler-Cromer method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method